# .NetWebApi: CORS error from production but okay from localhost using fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So this is my web api server config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[ApiRequireHttps]
[EnableCors("*","*","*")]
public class POSController : ApiController
{
      ......
}
```

Then this is how I call my fetch from another website:

```
var post = async (history: any, url: string, params: {} | null, data: any) => {
    nav = history;
    const response = await fetch(constructUrl(params, url), {
        mode: "cors",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': getAuthCookie(),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return await getResponse(response);
},

let res = await post(nav, '/api/pos/ownerRegister', null, {Email: viewModel.email, Password: viewModel.password, Name: viewModel.name});
```

This is really weird, because if I `fetch post` it from my `localhost`, it works, but if I call it from my production hosted at `https://example.com`, it fails.

The error is:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://myserver.com/api/pos/ownerRegister' from origin
> 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What am I missing here?

Comment: first of all, it seems to be an webapi 2.x? .netframwork 4.x?

Comment: CORS needs to be allowed by the SERVER - putting a response header like `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'` in the REQUEST only complicates issues - first step, remove that response header from the request headers - second step, allow cors from the server code

Comment: Its clear kestrel server, or you are using for example nginx reverse proxy?